# Unable to set android emulator display size

Tags: flutter

So I'm just starting to learn Flutter. I want to run the emulator. It works, but I can't adjust the display size.

[image]

I expecting it has a proper size. So how can I adjust the emulator display size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below key combinations for it:

1. If you are using Mac then you can do :

```
cmd + up arrow
```

2. And if you are using windows then:

```
Ctrl + up arrow
```

Hope it will solve your issue.